# Remote desktop DNS destination

Tags: remote-desktop

I don't know too much about networking but basically I'm going to China and am wondering how Remote Desktop connections work so that I can know whether or not those have the possibility of being blocked.

Does, for example, Microsoft Remote Desktop make connections to some server that Microsoft owns that then tunnels stuff to my computer? Or does Remote Desktop go directly to my PC? Because if it makes a DNS request to a dedicated Microsoft proxy server then clearly it could be easily blocked...

Thanks and let me know if this is wrong stackexchange I never know which stackexchange to go to

Comment: Correct forum. But it is customary to do own research first.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Remote Desktop uses port 3389 to go directly to your External IP address (router/firewall in your home/office) which then will need to be forwarded to your internal IP address of the machine that needs to be connected too.

The connection will go through whatever hops it needs to get to your External IP address. If there is a firewall or a proxy or a pipe under the sea it will attempt whatever route it can.

Baring this in mind the connection can be blocked by several different elements (off the top of my head):

1.Whatever the ISP or outgoing Proxy that is being used from your location in China.

2.The Chinese network infrastructure as a whole, I know that certain ports are blocked from incoming/outgoing China's network.

3.Your ISP locally to the PC your trying to connect too, for example some home ISP's in the UK block the remote desktop port 3389 as it is seen as 'business' use.

So its not quite as cut and dry as that really, like mentioned above you should perform some research but hopefully the above points you in some sort of correct direction.